# Remove coupon code from new order email and insert label of coupon instead

Tags: email, sales

Does anyone know how to edit the following to have the name of the coupon as the label on the new order sales email *instead* of the coupon code?

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
    <?php else:?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">
            <?php
            if ($_code=="discount") {
              $code_used = trim(str_replace(array("Discount (",")"),array(""),$this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel())));
              $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
              $coupon->load($code_used, 'code');
              $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($coupon->getRuleId());
              $rule_name = $rule->getName();
            }

            ?>
         <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
        <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento offers the possibility to add labels to your coupons. Check the 'Labels' tab while editing a discount rule. You can set a default value for the label (Default Rule Label for All Store Views) and/or separate labels for each store view.
That label is used everywhere the rule is used: in the cart totals, in the checkout totals, in the e-mail templates, in the order details view...
I would use that one instead of trying to display the name of the rule.

This feature is available starting Magento CE1.4/ EE1.9 (I think). If you are using that version or something higher it should be available.